# HTTP Post not working in my mobile

Tags: android, arrays, http-post

I am sending phone contacts as a json array to php server. It is sent successfully from HTC mobile. But not working in Samsung galaxy. Any idea?? Here is my code which works fine in HTC device.

```
public void postData(String id) {

        String URL =       "http://www.aheadsupapp.com/app/functions/save_phone_friends.php";
        JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray();
        Jarray = fetchContacts();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nVP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nVP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", id ));
        nVP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", Jarray.toString()));
        Log.d("Response","Entered Post");

        try{

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000); //Timeout Limit
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nVP, "utf-8"));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new  BasicResponseHandler();
            String phpResponse = client.execute(post, responseHandler);

            Log.d("Response", "PHP Response: " + phpResponse);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Response", "Catch: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: in catch block... i am getting null

Comment: the most surprising thing is, this code works fine in one mobile (htc) but not working in samsung.. I have tried two sumsung devices

Comment: @Abdellah this code even not enters the try block. in catch block i get null

Comment: @WasimAhmad the webservice http://www.aheadsupapp.com/app/functions/save_phone_friends.php return 0 ?!

Comment: @AndoMasahashi the complete log or just the response tag??

Comment: @Abdellah ... my code not execute the try block... why is this?? yes it gives zero as response... but that is not the problem...

Comment: `my code not execute the try block... why is this??` because you get `NPE` before `try catch`

Comment: yeah NullPointerException .. try to debug your code line by line

Comment: Log.d("Response", "Catch: " + e.getMessage()); this gives me null. and i am not getting any NPE... the code skips the try block and catch the exception in catch block... @Abdellah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure it depends on the Android version. Remember that you should not perform any interent activity in the main thread.You should use AsyncTask or Hanlders.
In older versions of Android it was allowed to run internet consuming threads in the main one , but since 4.0 it was denied.

Comment: ;) it happened to me before !